# Route an event into sibling control in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a TextBox control for search, and a TreeView control below it. What I need is when I press the "Down Key ↓" **while the focus on the search TextBox**, I need to tell the TreeView "**a Down Key has been pressed while the focus on you**" ... I don't need to raise a KeyUp event on the TreeView or something, I need it to do the same action as if I pressed the Down Key while the focus on it!

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like following:

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TreeView1.RaiseEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: thank you 'decyclone', but I have tried this and the action I want did not happened. This will raise the KeyUp event on the treeview and the event will wait for a handler ... what I need is: "make treeview do as if I pressed the X key while it is focused"

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox),
        TextBox.KeyUpEvent,
        new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(TextBox_KeyUp));

    base.OnStartup(e);
}

private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != System.Windows.Input.Key.Down) return;

    TreeViewItem newChild = new TreeViewItem();

    newChild.Header = "a Down Key has been pressed while the focus on you";

    Parent.Items.Add(newChild);
    e.Handled = true;
    //MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed");
}
```

Comment: thank you "eibhrum", I don't wanna add new node.
What will happened when I pressed Down Key when the focus on the tree view? i want this to happened exactly when I pressed Down Key while the focus on text box!